# $f:\mathbb X \to \mathbb X$ , $f^m(x) = f^n(x)$, f is onto, prove that f is one-one.

Tags: functions

$f:\mathbb X \to \mathbb X$

$f^m(x) =  f^n(x) $, m > n , m and n are integers.

$f^m$ is just $f \circ f \circ \dots f$ m times.

It is given that f(x) is onto. Prove that f(x) is one-one.

Comment: What does the notation $f^m(x)$ mean here? Composition or multiplication?

Comment: Edited, sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: The statements "$f(x)$ is into" and "$f(x)$ is one-one" do not make sense. This should be "$f$ is onto" and "$f$ is one-one" (for the later "$f$ is bijective" is preferable in my opinion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
For any $ x_1, x_2$ show that there exist $ y_1, y_2$ such that $f^n (y_i)=x_i.$ Then if $f(x_1)=f(x_2),$ we shall also have $f^m(y_1)=f^m(y_2).$ Thus... what?
Hope this helps.

Comment: umm, 
f(x1)=f(x2)
thus, f^n+1(y1)=f^n+1(y2)
thus,f^m(y1)=f^y(y2)
and this x1 = x2 . gee it was easy. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y=f^n(X)$. Let $k=m-n$, so $m=n+k$. By hypothesis we know $$f^k(f^n(x))=f^n(x)$$
which, if we set $y=f^n(x)$, reads as $f^k(y)=y$. That is to say, $f^k$ is the identity on $Y$. Since $f$ is onto $Y=X$. Now, if $f(x)=f(z)$ then 
$$x=f^k(x)=f^{k-1}(f(x))=f^{k-1}(f(z))=f^k(z)=z$$
which proves $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f$ is onto iff $k_1 \circ f = k_2 \circ f \Rightarrow k_1 = k_2$
A function $f$ is one-to-one iff $f \circ k_1 = f \circ k_2 \Rightarrow k_1 = k_2$

Then, since $f$ is onto, $f^m = f^n \Rightarrow f^{m-1} = f^{n-1} \Rightarrow \cdots \Rightarrow f^{m-n} = id $

If $f \circ k_1 = f \circ k_2$, then $f^{m-n} \circ k_1 = f^{m-n} \circ k_2 \Leftrightarrow k_1 = k_2$, concluding $f$ is one-to-one.